# ZF2 Redirect from phtml file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

is there a way to make a redirection from inside a phtml file in ZF2 Framework?

The reason is that I am using the jQuery $.POST mechanism (ajax) to refresh a part of the page, but I cannot make a redirection from the controller used by the ajax because it will load the new page into the div (which is inside another page).

I have tried using ZF2's :

```
$this->_redirect($this->url('restaurants'));
```

But I get a ServiceNotFoundException. I also tried php's:

```
<?php header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ; ?>
```

But this just did not work at all.

Hope this is clear enough!.. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is it that you're after? If you use Ajax to refresh the contents of your page why would you want to redirect to another page?

Comment: Why dont you just return to jQuery.POST an output of the required data. in a clean layout? (no headers...)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `header` when you printed anything before it. There must not be any output before `header`. So this means the exact same for `$this->_redirect()`.

What you could do is the following: 
Add this to your `head` section

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

or use javascript to redirect the user. If you don't want to extend your layout file you should use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
</script>
```

**EDIT**

After rereading your question i think the only possible way for you to redirect the user after you've received the page content is the javascript solution.

Comment: I agree its the easiest fix for this. But this means you are allowing scripts to be allowed(eval) from the response. This can cause XSS. The happy in between is to send a variable containing the url and use it in an ajax callback function.